# Analytical pseudo inverse of rank deficient matrix by QR decomposition

Tags: matrices, inverse

Given an overdetermined real linear system $Ax = b$, with $m$ equations, $n$ variables, and some unknown elements in both $A$ and $b$. I need to know what constraints must be imposed on those unknown elements (not the variables) so that the system becomes consistent and with a single solution (the solution itself doesn't matter).

The system must thus satisfy two conditions ($A^+$ is the Moore-Penrose pseudo inverse):

- $AA^+b = b$: the system is consistent
- $A^+A = I$: there is only one solution

The question is how to derive $A^+$? The Wikipedia page on the pseudo inverse lists various methods, but only one, QR decomposition, is not iterative or rely on $A$ being full rank (or at least having a known rank). QR decomposition can be carried out analytically (by using the Gram–Schmidt process, for example), but how can I obtain $A^+$ from $Q$ and $R$? I've googled for a few hours, but the only result found was (from [algopy](http://pythonhosted.org/algopy/examples/moore_penrose_pseudoinverse.html)): $A^+ = w$, where $w$ is the solution to $Rw = y$ and $y$ is the solution to $R^Ty = A^T$, but it assumes $A$ is full rank.

Comment: I think your question is a little too general.  We have a matrix A about which we know only that it is overdetermined.  We know nothing about the composition of A, which elements may be unknown, etc.  Likewise with b.  So I don't see how we could derive A+ when we know nothing about A.  Perhaps you could begin with a specific example of A and b, say A upper triangular with a11 unknown and all the other rows basis vectors; and maybe b1 unknown. See where that gets you.  It might throw some light on things.

Comment: @Betty Mock: the linear system is unconstrained, and I am hoping I can avoid special cases. My problem is, I have a collection of objects and a collection of sets, where set membership is controlled various constraints and represented by a linear system. If the system is consistent, the object is in, otherwise it's out. Instead of trying every object + set combination, I'm trying to find a way to speed things up by ruling out some combinations.

Comment: I suggested looking at some special cases not because that solves your problem per se, but because such cases often illuminate the situation.  I looked around a bit about pseudo inverses and found a suggestion of using the singular value decomposition, which seems to be a generalization of eigenvalue decomposition.  It does not depend on full rank.

Comment: @Betty Mock: I'll see if I can learn something from a few examples here. Regarding SVD, the analytical approaches I found are way over my head :(

Comment: When I get a little time I'll try to look into it.  I do like this pseudo inverse -- it looks so useful.  Keep working. You're bound to get somewhere (if not to exactly where you hoped).

Comment: Hi, I looked into plain old eigenvalue decomposition, and as I half remembered there is no easy way to do it, unless the size of the matrix is small.  So the singular value decomposition is not going to be any better.  Perhaps there is another way to grab hold of your problem?